# What is the recommended settings for video editing using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, linux

I am quite new for using `FFmpeg`, and I am using `FFmpeg` in screen recording. I checked the online documentation in this link [ffmpeg documentation "Capturing your Desktop / Screen Recording"](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop), but I didn't find sufficient information.

I have a 4k laptop with invidia GPU, and I am using the below command to screencast the video (4k, 60 f/s), and audio from my laptop.

```sh
ffmpeg -video_size 3840x2160 \
 -framerate 60 \
 -f x11grab -i :1 -f pulse -ac 2 -i default \
 -c:v libx264 \
 -crf 0 \
 -qp 0 \
 -preset ultrafast videoname.mp4
```

I have some problems in these settings as following:

1. The output video is too large, and I need to reduce the size without touch the quality at all.
2. The output video seems to be not a row video, and it takes too much time in video editing decoding and encoding. I am not sure if there is a recommended setting for video editing. As I did some search and found the above is advised, but in practice perspective, it is not efficient.

Below is my Linux distro information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description   : Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release       : 20.04
Codename      : focal
```

Comment: Welcome! Your 2 goals are potentially mutually exclusive. Usually you get better editing performance with less compressed source material. What editor are you using? What is your target audience? Do you really need 4k output?

Comment: As well as the raster size, do you really need 60fps? Are you slowing it down in post? If not you can halve the data rate by using 30fps

Comment: @MichaelLiebman I am using Hitfilm Pro 14. My target audiance are mainly technical and IT guys. Yes, I need 4K output this will be  a nice part in my videos..

Comment: @stib I am not sure if 60fps is required or not in screen recording for coding and presentation.

Comment: I think my main requirement is to enhance the video editing speed and make the quality 4K as is.

Comment: For screen recording, you could absolutely use a lower frame rate. Try 30 or 24 fps. Depending on your content, you could even go 15fps. Is there lots of smooth motion?

Comment: I am not sure, But I think this could reduce the size, but it is quite not affecting to make video editor more responsive and less slow when editing 4k.

Comment: And consider how people are going to be watching it. Mobile? On the web? Are people *actually* going to see it in 4k? And if they do is it going to be so compressed that it would look better in HD with less compression.

Comment: It depends on but some people are using youtube and most of them have a 4k screen.

Comment: You should investigate using proxies when you're editing. This lets you edit lower resolution copies, but use the full resolution when rendering. Not sure if Hitfilm does that though, you'll have to check the docs.

Comment: @stib Does ffpmeg has a recommeded encoding or format for editing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111994/discussion-between-stib-and-moustafa-mahmoud).